# Exponential search?

Tags: java, implementation

Does anybody have a Java implementation of exponential search? I cannot find anything about that algorithm and I have no idea of how to implement it. Something like:

```
 * Signature method that must implement exponential search.
 * @ Param searchArray integer array in ascending.
 * @ Param x integer element to search for.
 * @ Return integer containing the position in the array <CODE> searchArray <\ CODE>
 * In case the element <CODE> x <\ CODE> be located in this otherwise
 * <CODE> Returns NOT_FOUND </ CODE>

public int exponentialSearch (int [] searchArray, int x);
```

Comment: Do you mean logarithmic search?  Since the array is presorted, it can be searched in log(N) time (see @Makato answer).  And maybe somewhere along the line "logarithmic" got translated to "exponential" or some such.

Comment: It's unclear what you're searching for. The value x? This can be done in linear time. An exponential algorithm would be far less efficient...

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search), the exponential search algorithm assumes that the list is sorted and consists of two stages.

(1) determines in which (2<sup>k-1</sup>, 2<sup>k</sup>) interval (k >=1)  in which the search key is

(2) performs a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) in this interval

Pseudocode for a exponential search in an array of integers:

```
int exponentialSearch(int arr[], int size, int key)
{
    if (size == 0) {
        return NOT_FOUND;
    }

    int bound = 1;
    while (bound < size && arr[bound] < key) {
        bound *= 2;
    }

    return binarySearch(arr, key, bound/2, min(bound + 1, size));
}
```

The complexity of the algorithm is O(log i), in which i is the index of the search key in the array.

Answer (score -1):

I'm willing to bet that, instead of exponential search, this is a take on [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), in which your data is already sorted in ascending order.

It roughly follows these steps:

- You start at a point defined as the floor of the length of your array divided by 2.
- Compare the point with the value you want to find.
- If it matches, return the position in which you found it.
- If it's lesser, take a subset of the array from 0 to your start point (exclusive), and repeat the above steps.
- If it's greater, take a subset of the array from your start point + 1 and the rest of the array, and repeat the above steps.

Comment: IMHO the OP is talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search